# CPU Usage Static at 42% - Intel core i7 (Quad Core)

Tags: cpu, performance, cpu-usage, intel-core-i7

I have a HP dv5t 2100 CTO laptop with Intel core i7 (quad core) / 8GB RAM.

Recently I've noticed that the maximum CPU usage it attains is fixed at 42% - I mean it does not go beyond that come what may. This results in an overall laggard behaviour with basic apps taking quite some time to open.

Any ideas as to why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What application[s] have you used to verify this? Can you try with [AIDA64](https://www.aida64.com) or [Prime95](https://www.mersenne.org/download/)?

Comment: Check the process and memory in task manager. Something will tasks up a lot of cpu. usage.